# Retrieving data from JSON object using substring

Tags: javascript, json

If i have the following JSON object:

```
taxcodes = {
   "CA_MONO CO": {
          "Rate": 1,
          "Country": "United States"
       }
}
```

Using `taxcodes["CA_MONO CO"].Rate` works perfectly in retrieving the rate of `1`.

Now my issue is, if i had a variable lets say: `x = "CA_MONO CO_MAMMOTH LAKES"`.

`taxcodes[x].Rate` will not work obviously because of the `_MAMMOTH LAKES`.

So what I did was cut all strings after `CO_`, which gave me `CA_MONO` then added `' CO'` back on to the end of the string which gave me `CA_MONO CO`.

`var modifiedx = x.substring(0, x.indexOf('CO_')) + ' CO';`

I then attempted to pull the data using `taxcodes[modifiedx].Rate`, which did not pull the data.

Comment: Print out the value of `modifiedx` and examine it closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space when you append the `+ ' CO'`

```js
taxcodes = {
   "CA_MONO CO": {
          "Rate": 1,
          "Country": "United States"
       }
}

x = "CA_MONO CO_MAMMOTH LAKES"

var modifiedx = x.substring(0, x.indexOf('CO_')) + 'CO';

console.log(
 taxcodes[modifiedx].Rate
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have an extra space from `' CO'`. So the value was `"CA_MONO  CO"` rather than `"CA_MONO CO"`. Just remove it:

```
var modifiedx = x.substring(0, x.indexOf('CO_')) + 'CO';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var modifiedx = x.substring(0, x.indexOf('CO_')) + ' CO';
```

should be

```
var modifiedx = x.substring(0, x.indexOf('CO_')) + 'CO';
```